# Android Service donot get Bound

Tags: android, android-service, bindservice, onserviceconnected

Hi I am new to android and exploring the services part.I could not bind the service using bind method.I could not figure out whether it is problem with bind method or on service connected.Someone please help me with it.Thanks in advance

Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MyService pavan ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
    this.startService(i);
    System.err.println("before binding**************************");
    this.bindService(i, con, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    this.unbindService(con);this.stopService(i);
}
public ServiceConnection con = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        pavan = ((MyService.localbinder)service).getservice();
        System.err.println("here service gets binded");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Service connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"oops this is moment of Service disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
};
```

}

Service code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public MyService() {
}
public class localbinder extends Binder{
    public MyService getservice(){
        return MyService.this;
    }
}
IBinder ibinder = new localbinder();;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return ibinder;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}
```

}

manifest code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.coolguy.pract">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: How do you know, that your code does not work?

Comment: System.err.println("here service gets binded"); inside onserviceconnected is not being called.So i assumed that onserviceconnected is not being called

Comment: I even tried to invoke bind on button click since binding is async. but in vain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the problem in my code.Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE automatically invokes startService().So here when I invoked bind method since service is already running it goes to on onStartCommand.So just do not use startservice with Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag.